# How define an conditional "if exist" element, with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When you load a page with a student, at least two options appear for you to click (if they studied high school, in the same house of studies). But this is not always the case. I want to condition the following:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)

if not wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[text()='AC']/following-sibling::td/input"))):
    print('Cargando reporte...')
    time.sleep(6)
    driver.save_screenshot(r'C:\Users\spvda\Desktop\{}.-image.png'.format(i))
    driver.quit()   
else:
    ait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[text()='AC']/following-sibling::td/input"))).click()
    print('Cargando reporte...')
    time.sleep(6)
    driver.save_screenshot(r'C:\Users\spvda\Desktop\{}.-image.png'.format(i))
    driver.quit()
```

But, it don't work and get this: `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)` `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` (The message is empty).

How fix this?

Comment: Try/Except would be the "Best practice" in that case. It makes you handle different errors as you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find_elements` to have a list and can check if the size > 0 then do some stuff **othetrwise** do something else.

```
try:
    if(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='AC']/following-sibling::td/input"))) > 0:
        print("When AC is visible in UI")
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[text()='AC']/following-sibling::td/input"))).click()
        print('Cargando reporte...')
        time.sleep(6)
        driver.save_screenshot(r'C:\Users\spvda\Desktop\{}.-image.png'.format(i))
        driver.quit()
    else:
        print('Cargando reporte...')
        time.sleep(6)
        driver.save_screenshot(r'C:\Users\spvda\Desktop\{}.-image.png'.format(i))
        driver.quit()
except:
    print("Something went wrong")
    pass
```

Comment: The first conditional detects the button, but does not click the button.

Comment: cause the code isn't there to click, updated above, please try again

Comment: Forget it, I added in my code. Your code is correct. Thanks